# Connecting to Redshift when there's too many active connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We've started to get errors from some services that connect to our Redshift database, stating "connection limit "500" exceeded for non-bootstrap users". I do see that there's 500 connections confirmed on our AWS dashboard. I'd like to get some information about about these connections, and perhaps just terminate them.

[This support article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-troubleshoot-connection-errors/) gives some steps that seem like they would be useful, regarding the STL_CONNECTION_LOG and STV_SESSIONS tables, as well as the PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND command. But the issue is that I can't connect via the Query Editor to do that, because I get the same error about there being too many connections.

So, what should I do at that point? Should I be using a different type of account to connect to the database, which wouldn't result in this error? Is there another way to get this information?

Comment: It sounds like you have many things trying to query your redshift instance. Is your intended answer to make your Redshift more efficient and allow many connections?

Comment: Maybe eventually. But first I'd like to get information _about_ the connections before doing something like that. It might be the case that something's connecting to the database more than it should.

Comment: Ok, maybe the solution is how to restrict connections based on a conditions so you are allowed connect.  However, I think that is out of range for my skill set.